# Is there any way to know if the user is scrolling tableview up or down? in swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to listen tableview scrolled down or up, if is it possible, please let me know. thanks.

Comment: you can always track the contentoffset

Comment: UIScrollView has a `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate.

Answer (score 0):

In the ViewController that you have set as the delegate for the tableview, you can implement scrollView delegate functions as well as a tableView contains a scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` is subclass of `UIScrollView` so implementing

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

you will know when the `UITableView` is scrolled.